# linear independence in a function

Tags: linear-algebra

Say that functions $h$ and $y$ in $C(R)$ are such that $h(17)=1, h'(17)=0, y(17)=0, y'(17)=1$. Would $h$ and $y$ be linearly independent or dependent functions?

I believe that I should check to see if these could have linear combinations to where $h=y$ and $h'=y'$ but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: If the primes here mean derivatives are taken, do you mean to assume that $h,y$ are continuous on all of $\mathbb R$, and differentiable just at the point $x=17$?  Or do you know more about the smoothness of $h,y$?  If this came up in a Differential Equations class, I'd encourage you to think about the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) for motivation.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $ah+by=0$, which means that, *for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$*,
$$
ah(x)+by(x)=0
$$
Then, also $ah'(x)+by'(x)=0$.

Evaluate both for $x=17$ and conclude that…